# How to append values from multiple csv files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, import-from-excel

I'm trying to open and read multiple csv files. My goal is to get values from different columns/rows located in different csv's and put it into lists that I will use later to display in a table. I have been looking through online and found some information but I'm still having trouble getting it to work. I am receiving an error: `NameError:name 'row' is not defined`.

I am relatively new to python so I don't have to much experience with a lot of modules yet, so could you also let me know if there is a better way to attack this problem. Also, the directory I am using has other files inside besides just .csv's.

```
import os

testrank = []
directory = os.path.join("c:\\","Users\sm\OneDrive\TestProject")

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".csv"):
           f=open(file, 'r')
           if row['rankings'] == 6:
               testrank.append(row['Name'])
           f.close()

print(testrank)
```

Comment: `row` does not exist, because some lines of code are missing to read in a row (maybe) to process. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/csv.html under `csv.reader` for a short example that uses `row`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `row` has indeed not been set, so it cannot be used.
You first need to "read" the file `f`; create a "reader" where you can iterate among rows:

```
...
import csv 
   ...
   if file.endswith(".csv"):
      f=open(file, 'r')
      myfilereader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
      for row in myfilereader:
          if row['rankings'] == 6:
   ...
```